# oracle database cloning

Tags: oracle

i tried to clone one of my database in one machine to another machine.
the procedure is right i guess its getting mounted but am unable to go to open state.its showing errors as below.

**ORA-24324: service handle not initialized
ORA-01041: internal error. hostdef extension doesn't exist**

would anyone suggest me what the exact pblm is?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: What mechanism did you use to clone the database?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

perhaps this might help you:

Cause of your problem:
Some datafiles are offline.
ORACLE instance terminated. Disconnection forced so this might cause the datafiles to be offlined

Solution:
Check if you have a good backup from which you can restore any problematic data file.

1) first restore the problematic datafile.

2) mount the database

SQL > recover database;

And then try to open the database

SQL > alter database open ;

3) Try to find if there are any offline files by checking the recover_file.

SQL> select * from v$recover_file;

For example:-

11 OFFLINE OFFLINE
2489793132
30-JAN-09

20 OFFLINE OFFLINE
2489793132

4) Recover the offline datafiles that were appearing from above select statement,

i.e.

SQL> recover datafile 11,20;

Media recovery complete.

5) Bring these datafiles back online,

i.e

SQL> alter database datafile 11,20  online;

Database altered.

6) To ensure no more files just check again the recover_file view, then you can safely open the database

SQL> select * from v$recover_file;
no rows selected

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Did you also clone your Oracle home?
If yes, make sure your update your pfile/spfile with your new server name. 
Also, don't forget listener.ora.

Hope this helps.